# How to get distance of array in C/C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working in C/C++. I have a problem that need your help. I want to tracking the postion of number missing in the array and how many number are missed. Assume that I have a int array

```
A=[1,2,5,6,12]
```

Let see A array that at the position 2st, we lost 3 and 4. At postion 4th, we lost 7,8,9,10,11. So the my output are
First case

```
   A.postionloss=2   //number 2
   A.posstionduration=2
```

At the second case

```
   A.postionloss=4   //number 6
   A.posstionduration=5 //from 6 to 12
```

Could you see help me the my programming. I try to make it but it doesnot work

```
int* getduration(int pos,int pos_array[])
{
    int* s_pos_dur=new int[2];
    int next_pos_num;
    next_pos_num=pos_array[pos]-1;
    if(pos_array[pos]!=next_pos_num)
        {
        s_pos_dur[0]=pos;
        s_pos_dur[1]=pos_array[pos+1]-pos_array[pos]-1;
        }
    return s_pos_dur;
}
```

To run

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int pos_array[5];

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(pos_array)/sizeof(int);i++)
    {
    printf("Input %d=",i);
    scanf("%d",&pos_array[i]);
    }
    int* s_pos_dur_arr=new int[5];
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
    s_pos_dur_arr=getduration(j,pos_array);
    printf("Pos %d= And duration=%d\n",s_pos_dur_arr[0],s_pos_dur_arr[1]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "C/C++". If it were SO would have a tag for it.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 C++ to implement it. It can use C

Comment: In `sizeof(pos_array)/sizeof(int)`, `pos_array` is a pointer, not an array! Therefore the size calculation is wrong. Always pass arrays in C as pointer/size pair.

Comment: `A.posstionduration=6` --> `A.posstionduration=5`?

Comment: @user3677103 Please debug before asking here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition will always be true

```
 next_pos_num = pos_array[i] - 1;
    if (pos_array[i] != next_pos_num)
```

lets suppose `pos_array[i]` is 5, after first line execution it will become 4
and then you are comparing 5 with 4.

you need to fix you code.
you can do

```
if (pos_array[i] + 1 != pos_array[i + 1])
```

A working solution is this. The pos should be pass by reference

```
int* getduration(int &pos, int* pos_array)

int* s_pos_dur = new int[2];
int next_pos_num;

for (pos; pos<4; pos++)
{
    //next_pos_num = pos_array[i] +1;
    if (pos_array[pos] + 1 != pos_array[pos + 1])
    {
        s_pos_dur[0] = pos; //store possiton of loss
        s_pos_dur[1] = pos_array[pos + 1] - pos_array[pos];
        break;
    }
}
return s_pos_dur;
```

and you can call it like this

```
int pos_array[5] = { 1, 2, 5, 6, 12 };
int* s_pos_dur_arr = new int[5];
for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
{
    s_pos_dur_arr = getduration(j, pos_array);
    printf("Pos %d= And duration=%d\n", s_pos_dur_arr[0], s_pos_dur_arr[1]);

}
```